# Unable to store Database results into a Map

Tags: java, sql, dictionary, linked-list, resultset

I have made a Query as shown  above which fetched me folowing  results

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT category_id  , T1 FROM ca
+-------------+--------------------+
| category_id | T1                 |
+-------------+--------------------+
|           1 | Popcorn            |
|           2 | Popcorn            |
|           3 | Popcorn            |
|           4 | Popcorn            |
|           5 | Popcorn            |
|           6 | Popcorn            |
|           7 | Soft Drinks        |
|           8 | Soft Drinks        |
|           9 | Soft Drinks        |
|          10 | Soft Drinks        |
```

For each T1 coulmn , i am trying to store the category_id

so that it looks as

```
Popcorn=[
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
]

 SoftDrinks=[
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,

]
```

I have followed the below approach to accomplish this

```
Map<String,LinkedList<Integer>> categoryitemslist = new HashMap<String,LinkedList<Integer>>();

    PreparedStatement stmt2 = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT category_id  , T1 FROM categories  ;");
                   ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery();
            LinkedList<Integer> llist = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            while(rs2.next())
            {
                int category_id = (int)rs2.getInt("category_id");
                llist.add(category_id);
                categoryitemslist.put(rs2.getString("T1"), llist);
            }
```

Could anybody please let me know whats the mistake ??

The result i obtained is

```
{

    Popcorn=[
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30,
        31,
        32,
        33,
        34,
        35,
        36,
        37,
        38,
        39,
        40,
        41,
        42,
        43,
        44,
        45,
        46,
        47,
        48,
        49,
        50
    ],


    SoftDrinks=[
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30,
        31,
        32,
        33,
        34,
        35,
        36,
        37,
        38,
        39,
        40,
        41,
        42,
        43,
        44,
        45,
        46,
        47,
        48,
        49,
        50
    ],

}
```

Comment: how can I know the mistake when I don't even know the problem?

Comment: @Olayinka , I didn't get what you meant ??

Comment: what is the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you have a single list that contains all fetched IDs, and you're putting this list for every `T1`, while you need to create a new list for every unique `T1` and add results to the corresponding list:

```
while (rs2.next()) {
    int cid = rs2.getInt("category_id");
    String t1 = rs2.getString("T1");

    if (!categoryItemsList.containsKey(t1)) {
        categoryItemsList.put(t1, new LinkedList<Integer>());
    }

     categoryItemsList.get(t1).add(cid);
}
```

Comment: Explain the problem as well that OP is doing to make it clear if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should read this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

So you have initialized an empty Map

```
Map<String,LinkedList<Integer>> categoryitemslist = new HashMap<>();
```

When you call `get()`, if the key doesn't exist, a null value is returned.

Your mistakes

- You're using only one linked list. This implies that all keys will be mapped with the same value (list of values in your case). I'm pretty sure this wasn't your intention.
- You've failed to check if a value exists for a key, which is a very important part to avoid [`NPE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#Null_pointer).

Solution:

```
LinkedList<Integer> llist = new LinkedList<Integer>(); //remove this line
while(rs2.next()){
    int category_id = (int)rs2.getInt("category_id");
    String key = rs2.getString("T1");

    //get value
    LinkedList<Integer> llist = categoryitemslist.get(key);

    //check if value exists i.e. if value isn't null, else create a new value
    if(value == null){
        llist = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }

    //now we're sure value isn't null
    llist.add(category_id);
    categoryitemslist.put(key, llist);
}
```